# Recycler view not working when getting arraylist from realtime database

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

MainActivity

```java
Main activity:package com.example.recyclerview2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        ArrayList<AppointmentRequest> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // Firebase Realtime Database URL
        String databaseUrl = "https://recyclerview2-58202-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/";

        // Reference to the "Appointments" node
        DatabaseReference appointmentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(databaseUrl).getReference("Appointments");

        // Initialize ArrayList to store AppointmentRequest objects
        ArrayList<AppointmentRequest> appointmentsList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add a ValueEventListener to retrieve data
        appointmentsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot appointmentSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // Convert each child of "Appointments" to an AppointmentRequest object
                    AppointmentRequest appointment = appointmentSnapshot.getValue(AppointmentRequest.class);
                    if (appointment != null) {
                        appointmentsList.add(appointment);
                    }
                }

                // Do something with the retrieved data
                for (AppointmentRequest appointment : appointmentsList) {
                    list.add(appointment);
                }

                // Update UI on the main thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.err.println("Error reading data: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list));

    }
}
```

Myadapter:

```java
package com.example.recyclerview2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<AppointmentRequest> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AppointmentRequest> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (list != null && list.size() > position) {
            AppointmentRequest appointment = list.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(appointment.getPatientName());

            // Assuming your AppointmentRequest class has getDate() and getStartTime() methods
            holder.date.setText(appointment.getDate());
            holder.time.setText(appointment.getStartTime());

        } else {
            // Handle the case where the list or its elements are null
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

MyViewHolder:

```java
package com.example.recyclerview2;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView date, name, time;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientName);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
    }
}
```

Database:
The problem is that as soon as I log in, instead of showing data it draws me back to the login activity. Seems like the query and all doesn't work.

the code works with local appointrequest object. it is only crashing when I am getting the data from the realtime database. Please let me know what I can change.

[image]

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.